# SQLAlchemy does not respect cascade when deleting

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a simple database model. I want to delete the children as soon as the parent gets deleted. But that doesn't work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship


Base = declarative_base()

class Artist(Base):
    __tablename__ = "artist"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    songs = relationship("Song", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)


class Song(Base):
    __tablename__ = "song"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("artist.id", ondelete="cascade"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uri = "sqlite:///:memory:"
    engine = create_engine(uri)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    artist = Artist()

    session.add(artist)
    session.commit()

    session.add(Song(artist_id=artist.id))
    session.commit()

    session.delete(artist)
    session.commit()

    print("After delete, artist = {0}".format(session.query(Artist).count()))
    print("After delete song = {0}".format(session.query(Song).count()))
```

The output:
After delete, artist = 0
After delete, song = 1

So the song still exists. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The cascade docs state _When using SQLite, foreign key support must be enabled explicitly. See [Foreign Key Support](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-foreign-keys) for details._  Has this been enabled?

Comment: Thats the solution! Thank you!